# Verify enum parameter list?

Tags: php, mysql

Given an enum parameter list as PHP string, eg `$list = "'A', 'B'"` how to verify this is

**1)** valid and

**2)** safe?

What kind of characters are allowed in an enum? Can I verify this with a regex?

Comment: What do you mean by an "enum parameter list"?

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen I mean the list you need to provide when you create a table that has an enum

Comment: that's not an "enum parameter list". it's a string. php has no enums.  and exactly what do you mean, "safe"? A string is a string. it's harmless.

Comment: @Marc B: I am trying to verify no SQL injection will happen when the table with that enum string is created

Comment: @MarcB:  You haven't seen the kind of damage that I can do with a string.

Comment: well, yeah. it depends on what you DO with that string. but by itself, a string can't do anything. it's just some stuff in memory.

Comment: @Marc B: As as I said I am creating a table that has an enum and the possible enum options will be in that string

Comment: @MarcB: but Chuck Norris could make a string do something.

Comment: mysql enums can contain anything you want. they're just strings. they could raw binary garbage for all mysql cares. if you try to put something into an enum that isn't in the field's enum definition, it just won't go in.

Comment: @Marc B Then in that case how to prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: @MATH000 Use prepared statements or (less desirable) escape the data, just like for any other data type.